# Plyr Video Player on Gatsby

Tags: javascript, markdown, gatsby

I want to add plyr video player with selected options below to my gatsby blog. It takes video url from fetched json file. I just tried to add markdown it directly but it sometimes loading, sometimes not. Fetched url is changing from post to post.

Code

```
<video id="player" playsinline controls ></video>
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.4/plyr.js"></script>
<script>
var controls =['play-large', 'rewind','play','fast-forward','progress','current-time','duration','mute','volume','settings','pip', 'airplay','download','fullscreen'];
var player = new Plyr('#player', { controls });
fetch("test.url")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then( data => {
    player.source = {
      type: 'video',
      title: data[0].label,
      sources: [
        {
          src: data[0].file,
          type: data[0].type,
          size: 720,
        },
      ],
    };
})
</script>
```

Json Data

```
[{"label":"Original","file":"link.mp4","type":"video\/mp4"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just tried to add markdown it directly but it sometimes loading,
> sometimes not

You need to understand what's going on. You are loading an external script (from a CDN: https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.4/plyr.js) directly outside the scope of React and Gatsby. If the script has been loaded before you request it, it will work, otherwise, it won't. Of course, things get odd in a production environment (`gatsby build`), where the codes behave slightly differently.

If you are working in a React, you need to use a React-based dependency, in your case, [`react-plyr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-plyr). Once you have installed it with:

```
npm install react-plyr --save
```

You can simply use it by:

```
import Plyr from 'react-plyr';

const IndexPage =()=>{

  return (
    <Plyr
      type="youtube" // or "vimeo"
      videoId="CDFN1VatiJA"
    />
  )
}
```

*Note: The `videoId` can either be the video ID or URL for the media.*

At this point, you can choose the JSON or the markdown approach, what makes you feel comfortable. The important thing is to get the `videoId` parameter (the source) from each approach.

Here's a detailed article using Plyr + Gatsby: https://chaseohlson.com/plyr-gatsby-youtube-vimeo